# Reset a derived class object

Tags: c++, c++11

I'd like to achieve something like this below:

```
class A {
public:
    virtual void reset() {
    // 1). if there's no override to this function,
    // then whatever derived from A should get reset
    // to its constructed state, e.g. if B derives from
    // A, then *this = B();
    // 2). if there is an override to reset in the derived 
    // class, call the reset in the derived class
    }
};
class B: public A {
public:
    B() { std::cout<<"reset B"<<std::endl; }
    // no override of reset() here
}; 
class C: public A {
public:
    void reset() override {
        std::cout<<"reset C"<<std::endl;
    }
};
```

N.B. **A doesn't know which class will derive from it**, but whoever derive from it, if there is no reset() override in that derived class, calling A::reset() should reset the derived class object to its constructed state, i.e.

```
A* a = new B();
a->reset(); // -> this equals to *a = B();
```

However, if there is an override of reset() in the derived class, calling A::reset() should call the overridden reset(), i.e.

```
A* a = new C();
a->reset(); // -> this should call C::reset()
```

Comment: You might want to look up the [Curiously recurring template pattern (CRTP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).

Comment: My understanding is, that this is simply the default behavior of c++? What is my misunderstanding? So if you need a reset specific to B, write an override. To use CRTP to get knowledge to A while A derived via CRTP from B and then call B::reset sounds a bit mysterious :-)

Comment: @Klaus how do you achieve question 1). in my comment within A::reset()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment it can be solved with the help of the [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern), *and* another level of inheritance:

```
// The base class is just an abstract interface class
struct A
{
    virtual void reset() = 0;
};

template<typename T>
struct realA : public A
{
    void reset() override
    {
        *this = T();
    }
}

class B : public realA<B>
{
    ... whatever you need here...
};
```

Now you can do

```
A* a = new B;
a->reset();
```

and it should work as you seemingly want it.

You have the (now abstract) base class `A` which contains the interface needed. Then you have the template class `realA` which contains the implementation you have in your variant of the `A` class, most notably the `reset` function implementation. Then the classes like `B` (and `C` and others) which inherits from `realA` instead of `A`.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the accepted answer, there is an alternative approach.

```
A* a = new Derived();
if(typeid(&A::reset)==typeid(&Derived::reset))// no override
{ *a = Derived(); } // instead of calling a1->reset()
else { a->reset(); } // if there is override
```

The problem with the above is that only public member functions can be used.